# How can I put process into "uninterruptible sleep"?

Tags: unix, process, signals, coredump

I'm testing some functionality to monitor processes and I need to emulate long core dump with determined "delay" (for example I need to make a process to "dump core" for 30 seconds). I'm noticed that process that dumping a core is in uninterruptible sleep, so it can't be killed with SIGKILL, but when I'm trying to emulate this behavior using pipe commands that receives coredump I can easily kill such process. So is there some way to make process to get into uninterruptible sleep (with such status in **ps**) and make it ignore the SIGKILL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put a process in an interruptible sleep mode you will have to go into kernel code.
Using the functionality of `wake_up_interruptible` and spin locks you will be able to achieve this state.

Answer (score 12):

Most proper way is to use freezer cgroup. It puts process to uninterruptible sleep in case of FROZEN cgroup state.

```
# mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
# mount -t cgroup -ofreezer freezer /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
# mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/frozen
# echo FROZEN > /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/frozen/freezer.state
# echo `pidof you_process` > /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/frozen/tasks
```

To put again to interruptible sleep, just change cgroup state to THAWED.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.  For some reason, output of `ps aux` only reflected state `D` after I send SIGTERM to the process.

Answer (score 0):

One reliable (if complicated) way to do this is to hard-mount an NFS directory and then take down the NFS server.

Answer (score -4):

There is no way to block SIGKILL.  That's the purpose.  The big hammer approach to getting rid of a process.  The only way SIGKILL can block is if the process is locked in the kernel.

Comment: But during process of dumping core process is immune to SIGKILL.

Comment: Hence...blocked in the kernel.

Comment: If you have them blocked with STAT==D, at least on our systems (centos6.4) you cannot kill them, you need to address the underlying issue.